# Norm of a linear continuous form

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $E=\{f\colon[0,2]\to\mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ continuous} \}$ be a prehilbert space equipped with inner product: 
     $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^2 f(t)g(t)\, dt$$
And let :
    $$U\colon E \to\mathbb{R}$$
       $$f \mapsto \int_0^1 t^2 f(t)\, dt$$
I have proved that $u$ is linear and continuous, now show that :
         $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\leq\|u\|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$
Hint:take $f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I have proved  $\|u\|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, I need the first part of the inequality

Comment: I think you mean $1/(2 \sqrt{3})$, not $(1/2) \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ,yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a lower bound on $\|U\|$, take some nice function $f$ and compute $|U(f)|/\|f\|$.    But you can do better than $1/(2\sqrt{3})$.
You might as well have $f = 0$ on $[1,2]$ since that interval doesn't contribute to $U(f)$.

Comment: For f(t)=1/sqrt(2),  u(t)=1/(2 sqrt(3))

Comment: It's not clear enough to me